# The domain of the sum rule(probability: The logic of science)

Tags: probability-theory

Anyone read Probability Theory: The logic of Science.

**Please help**, I've been really stuck for ages at how the sum rule has it domain derived and I don't have any teacher to ask.

**Question**

How is the 2.50 derived. And could anyone point me in a direction of good books to have read in terms of analysing and deriving functions like this. I have read quite a bit about inference. But here is the mathematical knowledge that is missing for me. Are there any really good books for gaining knowledge about how to analyse and figure these steps out?

I get the conditions of extreme points {0,1} and that the function has to depend on the product rule which has already been derived.

And after some manipulation we end up with this expression:

[image]

**Now here comes the domain part**
[image]

Comment: If anyone can give me a tip on how to improve the question, such that it can be answered, or give me some direction for where increase my knowledge such that I can figure out what is going on I would be grateful